# scp -i my.key "Not a directory" bug - what alternative can I use?

Tags: ssh, scp

`scp` like `ssh` has an option `-i`. In SSH that's documented as `-i identity_file`, and I have a file which works with `ssh user@dest -i my.key` to log in to a device without a password. SCP documents the same option as

> `-i identity_file` Selects the **file** from which the identity
> (private key) for public key authentication is read. This option is
> **directly passed**  to ssh(1).

(emphasis mine). This documentation is clearly wrong, because `scp my.file user@dest:/home/user/ -i my.key` fails with

> my.key: Not a directory

No, it's indeed not a directory. Clearly `scp` is not directly passing the argument to `ssh`, it does a check first, and that check in `scp` is probably the wrong way around (give an error if the argument **is** a directory)

Anyway, since `scp -i` is broken, what can I use instead? SCP version is from Debian 10, man page is dated 2018, no `--version` option available

Comment: this might not be the `scp` you are looking for, can you add result of `command -v scp`, `whereis scp` and `which scp` ? do you still have an error using `/usr/bin/scp -i my.key ...` ?

Comment: @Archemar: `/usr/bin/scp`, right beside `/usr/bin/ssh`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specify the options *before* the sources and target:

```
scp -i my.key my.file user@dest:/home/user/
```

See [the synopsis in `man scp`](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#SYNOPSIS):

> **scp** [**-346ABCpqrTv**] [**-c** *cipher*] [**-F** *ssh_config*] [**-i** *identity_file*] [**-J** *destination*] [**-l** *limit*] [**-o** *ssh_option*] [**-P** *port*] [**-S** *program*] *source* ... *target*

The error you’re seeing is the result of `scp` interpreting `my.file`, `user@dest:/home/user`, and `-i` as sources, and `my.key` as the target: it checks that the target is a directory, and fails because it’s a file.

Comment: Works. Weirdly enough `ssh` has the same documented requirement, but it _does_ accept a trailing `-i identity_file` option.

Comment: So it does, as long as you don’t specify a command! I can see how that would be confusing...

Comment: Personally, I blame the GNU people for this one. Most GNU tools just let you do that, even though POSIX is pretty explicit about putting options before operands.